# Single CV yields higer prediction error estimate compared to nested CV

Tags: regression, cross-validation, python, random-forest, scikit-learn

I'm trying to calculate an unbiased prediction error estimate for a regression problem with random forest. Dataset dimension is ~25100x13.

So, as a first step, I used a nested 10/10-fold CV loop which yielded an $R^2$ estimate of 0.87 ($\pm$ 0.01) (I thought this was really high). So I tried to perform the nested CV loop repeatedly (10 times), but consistently got an estimate really close to the original one. Additionally, I performed the same procedures on a randomly generated dataset of the same dimensions, to make sure this is not some kind of glitch in my code. This resulted in $R^2 < 0$.

Satisfied, I then proceeded to use a single 10-fold CV loop for model selection, which surprisingly resulted in $R^2$ = 0.78.

I thought that nested CV removes the optimism, associated with performing hyperparameter selection on the same data, on which model evaluation is performed, but in my case the opposite seems to be true.

So either nested CV is somehow allowing some optimism still, or a single 10-fold CV includes some pessimistic bias. I'm not really sure how to interpret these results. Any hints appreciated.

**[EDIT]** Forgot to add that I'm using randomized search for hyperparameter optimization with 60 iterations.
**[EDIT2]** Here's the code I'm using:

*Model evaluation*

```
outer_scores = {'best_param': [], 'r2': []}
print 'Starting nested cross-validation...'
outer = cross_validation.KFold(len(y), n_folds=10, shuffle=True)
for fold, (train_index_outer, test_index_outer) in enumerate(outer):
    np.random.seed(None)
    X_train_outer, X_test_outer = X[train_index_outer], X[test_index_outer]
    y_train_outer, y_test_outer = y[train_index_outer], y[test_index_outer]

    print 'Cross-validating on fold %i' % fold
    rs = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor, params, n_iter=60, n_jobs=-2, verbose=1, iid=False, refit=True, cv=10, scoring='r2',)
    rs.fit(X_train_outer, y_train_outer)

    pred_outer = rs.predict(X_test_outer)

    r2 = r2_score(pred_outer, y_test_outer)
    print "INNER R2: %.3f" % r2

    outer_scores['best_param'].append(rs.best_params_)
    outer_scores['r2'].append(r2)

print np.mean(outer_scores['r2']) # this returns the high $R^2$
```

*Model selection*

```
reg = RandomizedSearchCV(RandomForestRegressor, params, n_iter=60, n_jobs=-2,
                        verbose=1, iid=False, refit=True, cv=10, scoring='r2',
                        random_state=1)
reg.fit(X, y)
return reg.best_score_ # this returns lower $R^2$, than the code above
```

Comment: could you include the minimal code example reproducing the odd result

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling, I added the minimal code to reproduce the problem

Comment: I'm not a regular sklearn/pyhton user myself, but I really enjoy reading the documentation:) Ok wild guess  #1: I see you use either separate r2_score function or the .best_score_ attribute from RandomizedSearchCV. Perhaps these two metrics are by default not exactly alike. Try extract best parameters from R...SearchCV and then validate such a model in 10fold CV and use the r2_score. And repeat either procedure 20 times with new random seeds to make sure it is not just a random difference.

Comment: I guess a fully reproducible example would technically also include a link or a simulated data set.

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling, so I checked sklearn`s source and internally RandomizedSearchCV is calling r2_score, so that's fine. I repeated the procedure like 5 times, but consistently got similar result (it would take too much time to run it 20 times). Unfortunately, I cannot provide the data, and it would take too much time to produce a simulated dataset. I guess what I'm asking here, is if I'm making some really crude mistakes in the analysis. If not, I'll just consider this as some weird quirk of the data.